# Scan some text in a document, replace certain words(these words should be variables) and save in a new document using Apache POI in Java

Tags: java, json, gson, apache-poi

I have json file from which I parse json objects to java objects using Gson library. The next step is to create main class in which with the help of Apache POI prepared docx file is read, some changes were made in the text and new document with changes is created. The problem I faced is that the text which should be changed need to be variable(from json file). I mean that "name" and "testName" both should be variables or methods, so I can call them from text.contains. Can you show my mistake and the right way to do the task. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code  `

```
 public class main {
 public static void gson() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("jsonn.json"));
        Result result = gson.fromJson(br, Result.class);
        if (result != null) {

            result.getName();
            result.getLastname();
            System.out.println(result.getName());
            System.out.println(result.getLastname());
            for (Phone p : result.getPhones()) {
                p.getType();
                p.getNum();
                System.out.println(p.getType() + ": " + p.getNum());
                // System.out.println(p.getType()+" : "+p.getNum());
            }

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}}


public class Result {
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("lastname")
@Expose
private String lastname;
@SerializedName("phones")
@Expose
private List<Phone> phones = null;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public List<Phone> getPhones() {
    return phones;
}

public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
    this.phones = phones;
}}



public class Phone {
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("lastName")
@Expose
private String lastName;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@SerializedName("num")
@Expose
private String num;
@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;

public String getNum() {
    return num;
}

public void setNum(String num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}}



public class Read {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, 
IOException {

    main.gson();

    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("Шаблон.docx"));
    Result res = new Result();
    String replaceName = res.getName();
    for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
        if (runs != null) {
            for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                String text = r.getText(0);
                if (text != null && text.contains("name")) {
                    text = text.replace("name", "Alex");
                    r.setText(text, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (XWPFTable tbl : doc.getTables()) {
        for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
            for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
                    for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                        String text = r.getText(0);
                        if (text != null && text.contains("name")) {
                            text = text.replace("name", "Alex");
                            r.setText(text, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    doc.write(new FileOutputStream("Пример.docx"));

}}
```

`

Here is json file:

```
{
"name":"testName",
"lastname":"testLastName",
"phones":[
{
  "num":"9000000",
  "type":"mobile"
},
{
  "num":"1000000",
  "type":"home"
} ]}
```

Comment: There are loads of high quality, fully tested JSON parsers in Java. Why are you trying to write you own one badly, rather than just using an existing tested one?

Comment: Could you give advice of tested parsers? Apparently I don't know them. However it doesnt't solve my problem I guess. The task was to use gson so I thought this is the way to write my own.